# Problem with operator <

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I have a problem with the operator < that i wrote:

in Node.h :

```
.
..
bool operator<(const Node<T>& other) const;
const T& GetData ();
.
..
template <class T>
const T& Node<T>::GetData () {
 return m_data;
}

template <class T>
bool Node<T>:: operator<(const Node<T>& other) const
{
 return (*(this->GetData()) < *(other.GetData()));
}
```

in Heap.h :

```
template<class T>
void Heap<T>::Insert(Node<T>* newNode) {
 if (m_heap.size() == 0) {
  m_heap.push_back(newNode);
 }
 else
  DecreaseKey(newNode);  
}

template<class T>
void Heap<T>::DecreaseKey(Node<T>* newNode) {
 m_heap.push_back(newNode);
 int index = m_heap.size();
 while ((index > 1) && (m_heap[(index/2)-1] < (m_heap[index-1]))) { // doen't do the operator < !
  Exchange(index,index/2);
  index = index/2;
 }
}
```

in Vehicle.h:

```
bool operator< (const Vehicle& otherVehicle) const;
```

in Vehicle.cpp:

```
bool Vehicle::operator<(const Vehicle& otherVehicle) const {
 return (GetDistance() > otherVehicle.GetDistance());
}
```

in main.cpp:
.

```
..
 Node<Vehicle*> a(car1);
 Node<Vehicle*> b(car2);
 Heap<Vehicle*> heap;
 Node<Vehicle*>* p = &a;
 Node<Vehicle*>* q = &b;
 heap.Insert(p);
 heap.Insert(q);
 heap.ExtractMin()->GetData()->Show();
.
..
```

Why it doen't do the compeare ? with opeartor < , note: it pass the compiler.

Comment: Please try to post code as minimal as possible. If you state your problem _above_ all the code, it helps the reading a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you used Vehicle*, not Vehicle.

Comment: Create a wrapper class for Vehicle* and store/compare them instead.

Comment: @Gil: No, you made a class that would work for Vehicle. You never wrote code that would handle the case where the type in question is a pointer type.

Answer (score 3):

`m_heap` is a container of pointers. In this case you should dereference the node pointers:

```
while ((index > 1) && (*m_heap[(index/2)-1] < (*m_heap[index-1])))
```

This should now call `operator<` for Nodes, which in turn calls `operator<` for Vehicles.

Answer (score 1):

Use std::priority_queue instead of Heap, or any other heap that allows you to define custom comparison predicate.

Answer (score 0):

From what I see m_heap stores pointer to Node

```
 while ((index > 1) && (m_heap[(index/2)-1] < (m_heap[index-1]))) { // doen't do the operator <
```

I guess this should do

```
while ((index > 1) && (*(m_heap[(index/2)-1]) < *(m_heap[index-1]))) {
```

Comment: O.k ... now it make error C662: 'Node<T>::GetData' : cannot convert 'this' pointer form 'const Node<T>' to 'Node<T>&'

Comment: declare GetData with const => "const T& Node<T>::GetData () const"

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer: don't use pointers.**  You probably don't need them.

If possible, it's much easier to get this kind of code correct if you use plain objects.  If you need to use the concept of a pointer, use a pointer-container class, i.e. a wrapper that is passed around as a plain object with value semantics and potentially custom overloads such as the operator< you're using, but which hides the implementation pointer internally.

That way, you don't need to deal with pointers all over your app, but only where semantically relevant.