# Operation overloading C++ in a MANAGED C++ project

Tags: c++, visual-c++, operator-overloading

I've a managed C++ dll which talks with a C# GUI. It works fine, the communication goes through a wrapper and it all works. The code inside the dll is all written in C++, but I can't get operator overloading working and im planning to use it for sorting vectors. I don't know if there's an error in my code or if it doesn't work because it's in a managed C++ project.

I've tried the sort(it, it) but it doesn't work because the operator overloading doesn't work. I've also tried to use the compare sort(it, it, less_than_second), and that also doesn't work because I get errors. I've tried alot of things and I got errors like:
- Sort only takes 2 arguments
- less_than_second_ undeclared identifier

The operator overloading doesn't produce errors.

Here's the code of the move class where I want to overload the operator <:

```
public class Move
{

public:
    friend bool operator < (const Move &firstMove, const Move &secondMove)
    {
        return (firstMove.score < secondMove.score);
    }
    bool operator<(const Move& b) {
     return this->score < b.score;
    }
    int positionFrom;
    int positionTo;
    int tileFrom;
    int score;
    bool isJumpMove;
    Move(void);
    Move(int to);
    Move(int from, int to, bool isJumpMove);
    Move(int from, int to, int tileFrom, bool isJumpMove);


};

Testcode in a function of another class.

Move* move1 = new Move();
        move1->score = 2;
        Move* move2 = new Move();
        move2->score = 1;
        Move* move3 = new Move();
        move3->score = 0;
        Move* move4 = new Move();
        move4->score = 4;

        if(move1 < move2)
        {
            Console::WriteLine("2 is bigger than 1");
        }
        else
        {
            Console::WriteLine("1 is bigger than  2");
        }

        vector<Move*> vectorList;
        vectorList.push_back(move1);
        vectorList.push_back(move2);
        vectorList.push_back(move3);
        vectorList.push_back(move4);

        for (int i=0; i<vectorList.size(); i++) {
         Console::WriteLine(vectorList[i]->score);
        }
        sort (vectorList.begin(), vectorList.end() );
        sort (vectorList.begin(), vectorList.end(), less_than_second);
        for (int i=0; i<vectorList.size(); i++) {
         Console::WriteLine(vectorList[i]->score);
        }
the compare function ( it's in the cpp file of another class )

inline bool less_than_second( Move &move1,Move &move2){
        return (move1.score < move2.score);
    }
```

Comment: I don't see any managed code here, MEC++ or C++/CLI.  Retagging as `visual-c++` in case the compiler makes a difference, but I don't think it does.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Problem with operator <](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3759461/problem-with-operator)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your vector elements are `Move*` (a pointer).  This is a built-in type, you can't redefine its operators.  And `less_than_second` has the wrong signature, it doesn't accept pointers.

Comment: Also, `const`-ness may give errors. Try `bool less_than_second(const Move* pMove1, const Move* pMove2)`.

Comment: Where do you suggest to put that function? Because I've changed it to your suggestion but I still get the same error.

Comment: @qkp: The compiler can't find the function because it's in a different file.  Add a forward declaration in an appropriate header file or, since you want it inlined, put the whole definition in a header file.

Comment: I have it like this i've the Engine class and the Move class. I'm doing the sorting in the Engine class so the engine class calls less_than_second when doing sort(it.begin(), it.end(), less_than_second). Now I've the less_than_second function in the engine.cpp file. Do you suggest I put the less_than_second function in the engine.h file ? But where in the engine.h file? Inside the engine class or outside the engine class? Thanks!

Comment: Ah I got the sorting to work ! thanks alot! :D I've put the less_than_second function in the engine.h file but outside the class. But I still don't understand why the operator overloading "<" doesn't work..

Comment: @qkp: Because `std::sort` is comparing two vector elements, which are both pointers.  Section `[expr.rel]` in the standard defines the behavior of pointer comparison.  You can only redefine operators where at least one operand is a class type.  `Move*` is a pointer, not a class type, so you can't redefine `operator<(Move*, Move*)`.  You've successfully redefined `operator<` for `Move` objects, though, `*move1 < *move2` will call your implementation.  But `move1 < move2` compares pointers, not `Move` objects.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! :) I understand now, hope I won't make the same mistake in the future again.

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure you need to define your boolean operators outside of your class, comparing two objects is not an implicit part of a class, its external to the objects being compared.

Comment: Where do you suggest I put that function in? ( what file and how do I call the function then )

Comment: prototype goes int he header file outside the class definition and implementation goes in the implementation file.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confusing two different ways that the word overloading is used.  Operator overloading mean to provide mechanism to act on your user type as if it were a language primitive type.  function overloading means that you have two or more functions with the same name but different parameters.  For each operator is c++ you have a spesfic definition you must match while you can define multiples for parameter overloading of derived types it will allays contain the same number of parameters.

Comment: But they aren't different.  Overload resolution happens for operators just like other functions, choosing the best match for the parameters (operand are treated as parameters).

Comment: My point is you cant arbitrarily create operator definition.  I can't have a three parameter <

Comment: I need operator overloading for method 1 with sorting BUT the function overloading sort with 3 parameters which is standard in Algorithm stl doesn't work aswell for method 2.

Answer (score 0):

I recall that logical and arithmetic operator overloading for .NET in C# requires you use 
reflection.emit at the intermediate language level. You can test for Type.IsPrimitive.

public delegate TResult BinaryOperator

```
      TResult>(TLeft left, TRight right);



/// <summary>

/// See Stepanov and McJones BinaryOperator

/// </summary>

/// <typeparam name="TLeft"></typeparam>

/// <typeparam name="TRight"></typeparam>

/// <typeparam name="TResult"></typeparam>

/// <typeparam name="TOwner"></typeparam>

static class GenericOperatorFactory<TLeft, TRight, TResult, TOwner>

{

    private static BinaryOperator<TLeft, TRight, TResult> add;

    private static BinaryOperator<TLeft, TRight, TResult> sub;

    private static BinaryOperator<TLeft, TRight, TResult> mul;

    private static BinaryOperator<TLeft, TRight, TResult> div;



    public static BinaryOperator<TLeft, TRight, TResult> Add

    {

        get

        {

            if (add == null)

            {

                // For debugging

                Console.WriteLine("Creating Add delegate for:\nTLeft = {0}\n" +

                "TRight = {1}\nTResult = {2}\nTOwner = {3}", 

                typeof(TLeft), typeof(TRight), typeof(TResult), typeof(TOwner));



                DynamicMethod method = new DynamicMethod(

                    "op_Addition:" + typeof(TLeft).ToString() + ":" + typeof(TRight).ToString() + ":" + typeof(TResult).ToString() + ":" + typeof(TOwner).ToString(),

                    typeof(TLeft),

                    new Type[] { typeof(TLeft), typeof(TRight) },

                    typeof(TOwner)

                );



                ILGenerator generator = method.GetILGenerator();



                generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);

                generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);



                if (typeof(TLeft).IsPrimitive)

                {

                    Console.WriteLine("Adding primitives");

                    generator.Emit(OpCodes.Add);

                }

                else

                {

                    Console.WriteLine("Adding non-primitives");

                    MethodInfo info = typeof(TLeft).GetMethod(

                        "op_Addition",

                        new Type[] { typeof(TLeft), typeof(TRight) },

                        null

                    );



                    generator.EmitCall(OpCodes.Call, info, null);

                }



                generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);



                Console.WriteLine("Method name = " + method.Name);



                add = (BinaryOperator<TLeft, TRight, TResult>)method.CreateDelegate(typeof(BinaryOperator<TLeft, TRight, TResult>));

            }



            return add;

        }   

    }
```

There are several other examples on the internet

Comment: This question isn't about C#.  All the code is C++.  The C++ functions might someday be called by C#, but that's beside the point.